# Union Columns Vertically in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Assume these Tables:

**Group**: (Id, Title):  `{1,G1}, {2,G2}, {3,G3}, {4, G4}`

**Category**: (Id, Title): `{1, Cat1}, {2, Cat2}, {3, Cat3}, {4, Cat4}`

**Product**: (Id, GroupId, CategoryId, Name):

```
{1, 1, 1, G1C1P1},
{2, 1, 2, G1C2P2},
{3, 1, 2, G1C2P3},
{4, 2, 2, G2C2P4},
{5, 2, 2, G2C2P5},
{6, 3, 1, G3C1P6},
{7, 3, 3, G3C3P7}
```

**Dealer**: (Id, Name):  `{1, 'Dealer1'}, {2, 'Dealer2'}, {3, 'Dealer3'}`

**ProductDealer** (Id, ProductId (UK), DealerId, LastSale, Number):

```
{1, 1, 1, 5, '2012-12-10 12:34:31'}, 
{2, 2, 2, 120, '2012-11-10 12:34:31'}, 
{3, 5, 1, 75, '2012-12-02 12:34:31'}
```

So I going to create a full view of product, this is my first try:

```
SELECT 
    [PR].[Id],
    [PR].[Name],
    [PR].[GroupId],
    [GR].[Title] AS [Group],
    [PR].[CategoryId],
    [CA].[Title] AS [Category]

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [PR]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [GR] ON [PR].[GroupId] = [GR].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [CA] ON [PR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[Id]
```

Then I think to add `ProductDealer` columns to view, so I try this one:

```
SELECT 
    [PR].[Id],
    [PR].[Name],
    [PR].[GroupId],
    [GR].[Title] AS [Group],
    [PR].[CategoryId],
    [CA].[Title] AS [Category],
    ISNULL(
    (SELECT [PD].[Id] FROM [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] 
     WHERE [PD].[ProductId] = [PR].[Id]),
     CAST(-1 AS BIGINT)
    ) AS [ProductDealerId],
    ISNULL(
    (SELECT [DE].[Id] FROM [dbo].[Dealer] AS [DE]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] ON [DE].[Id] = [PD].[DealerId]
     WHERE [PD].[ProductId] = [PR].[Id]),
     CAST(-1 AS BIGINT)
    ) AS [DealerId],
     ISNULL(
    (SELECT [DE].[Name] FROM [dbo].[Dealer] AS [DE]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] ON [DE].[Id] = [PD].[DealerId]
     WHERE [PD].[ProductId] = [PR].[Id]),
     CAST('HaveNotDealer' AS NVARCHAR)
    ) AS [Dealer],
    ISNULL(
    (SELECT [PD].[LastSale] FROM [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] 
     WHERE [PD].[ProductId] = [PR].[Id]),
    CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:01' AS DATETIME2)
    ) AS [LastSale],
    ISNULL(
    (SELECT [PD].[Number] FROM [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] 
     WHERE [PD].[ProductId] = [PR].[Id]),
    CAST(0 AS BIGINT)
    ) AS [SaleNumber]

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [PR]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [GR] ON [PR].[GroupId] = [GR].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [CA] ON [PR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[Id]
```

As you see for each column in `ProductDealer` I write a full select query I don't know is there any better way to do this? something like union this columns to first view, what is your suggestion to best implement it?

**Update**

In `ProductDealer` Table, the `ProductId` is UK, So each Product could have one dealer or nothing, I want if the product have a dealer get `ProductDealer` Columns in view and if not get my default values like: (-1, 'HaveNotDealer').

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer in what you're trying to achieve.  Is it the case that for each product, you want the details of each dealer of that product tacked on to the end columns and the number of sales (or some other summary)?  Or do you want something like  [PRODUCT COLUMNS] [Column for first dealer] [Column for second dealer] [...] - if that's the case then I suggest that should be something best done in your presentation layer if possible.

Comment: @Ian Yates in `ProductDealer` Table `ProductId` is UK, So each Product could have one dealer or nothing, I want if the product have a dealer get `ProductDealer` Columns in view and if not get My default values like: (-1, 'HaveNotDealer')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    [PR].[Id],
    [PR].[Name],
    [PR].[GroupId],
    [GR].[Title] AS [Group],
    [PR].[CategoryId],
    [CA].[Title] AS [Category],
    ISNULL([PD].[Id],
    CAST(-1 AS BIGINT)) AS [ProductDealerId],
    ISNULL([D].Id,
    CAST(-1 AS BIGINT)) as DealerId,
    ISNULL([D].Name,
    CAST('HaveNotDealer' AS NVARCHAR)) as DealerName,
    ISNULL(PD.LastSale,
    CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:01' AS DATETIME2)) as LastSale,
    ISNULL([PD].Number,
    CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) as SaleNumber

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [PR]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [GR] ON [PR].[GroupId] = [GR].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [CA] ON [PR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ProductDealer] AS [PD] ON [PR].[Id] = [PD].[ProductId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Dealer] AS [D] ON [PD].DealerId = [D].Id
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps only answering this question in "spirit", but this is the "Union Columns Vertically" answer I was looking for when I stumbled upon this Question =)

```
with aa(col1, col2) as (
    select * from (values (1,2) ) blah
),
 bb(col3, col4) as (
    select * from (values (5,6) ) blah
)

select select aa.col1, aa.col2, bb.col3, bb.col4
from aa , bb
```

Gives

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
1   |2   |5   |6
```

**Disclaimer** The above only works cleanly for single row `aa` , `bb` .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "vertical UNION" version:

```
WITH "Group"
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1,'G1'), (2,'G2'), (3,'G3'), (4, 'G4')
             ) AS T (Id, Title)
     ),
     Category
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Cat1'), (2, 'Cat2'), (3, 'Cat3'), (4, 'Cat4')
             ) AS T (Id, Title)
     ),
     Product
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'G1C1P1'),
                     (2, 1, 2, 'G1C2P2'),
                     (3, 1, 2, 'G1C2P3'),
                     (4, 2, 2, 'G2C2P4'),
                     (5, 2, 2, 'G2C2P5'),
                     (6, 3, 1, 'G3C1P6'),
                     (7, 3, 3, 'G3C3P7')
             ) AS T (Id, GroupId, CategoryId, Name)
     ),
     Dealer
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Dealer1'), (2, 'Dealer2'), (3, 'Dealer3')
             ) AS T (Id, Name)
     ),
     ProductDealer 
     AS
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 1, 1, 5, '2012-12-10 12:34:31'), 
                     (2, 2, 2, 120, '2012-11-10 12:34:31'), 
                     (3, 5, 1, 75, '2012-12-02 12:34:31')
             ) AS T (Id, ProductId, DealerId, Number, LastSale)
     )     
SELECT PR.Id, PR.Name, PR.GroupId, GR.Title AS "Group",
       PR.CategoryId, CA.Title AS Category, 
       PD.Id AS ProductDealerId,
       D.Id DealerId,
       D.Name AS DealerName,
       PD.LastSale AS LastSale,
       PD.Number AS SaleNumber
  FROM Product AS PR
       JOIN "Group" AS GR ON PR.GroupId = GR.Id
       JOIN Category AS CA ON PR.CategoryId = CA.Id
       JOIN ProductDealer AS PD ON PR.Id = PD.ProductId
       JOIN Dealer AS D ON PD.DealerId = D.Id

UNION

SELECT PR.Id, PR.Name, PR.GroupId, GR.Title AS "Group",
       PR.CategoryId, CA.Title AS Category, 
       PD.Id AS ProductDealerId,
       CAST(-1 AS BIGINT) DealerId,
       CAST('HaveNotDealer' AS NVARCHAR) AS DealerName,
       PD.LastSale AS LastSale,
       PD.Number AS SaleNumber
  FROM Product AS PR
       JOIN "Group" AS GR ON PR.GroupId = GR.Id
       JOIN Category AS CA ON PR.CategoryId = CA.Id
       JOIN ProductDealer AS PD ON PR.Id = PD.ProductId
 WHERE PD.DealerId NOT IN ( SELECT Id FROM Dealer )

UNION

SELECT PR.Id, PR.Name, PR.GroupId, GR.Title AS "Group",
       PR.CategoryId, CA.Title AS Category, 
       CAST(-1 AS BIGINT) AS ProductDealerId,
       CAST(-1 AS BIGINT) DealerId,
       CAST('HaveNotDealer' AS NVARCHAR) AS DealerName,
       CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:01' AS DATETIME2) AS LastSale,
       CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS SaleNumber
  FROM Product AS PR
       JOIN "Group" AS GR ON PR.GroupId = GR.Id
       JOIN Category AS CA ON PR.CategoryId = CA.Id
 WHERE PR.Id NOT IN ( SELECT ProductId FROM ProductDealer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    [PR].[Id],
    [PR].[Name],
    [PR].[GroupId],
    [GR].[Title] AS [Group],
    [PR].[CategoryId],
    [CA].[Title] AS [Category],
    PD.ID AS ProductDealerID,
    PD.DealerId,
    DE.Name AS Dealer,
    PD.LastSale,
    PD.Number AS SaleNumber

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [PR]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [GR] ON [PR].[GroupId] = [GR].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [CA] ON [PR].[CategoryId] = [CA].[Id]
LEFT JOIN  ProductDealer AS [PD] ON PD.ProductId = PR.ID
LEFT JOIN  Dealer AS DE ON DE.ID = PD.DealerId
```